# Modify the tab bar through an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does the extension api have access to the tab bar?
I would like to modify it, show only certain tabs at a time.

Comment: the per-editor group editor tab bar? and what do you want to the other tabs you don't let be shown?

Comment: I mean the normal tab bar. I would like to only show the current tab and the last 3 visited tabs, and make the rest invisible. I mostly switch tabs  through ctrl+p, I want to use the tab bar more like information and quick access to recent documents.

Comment: write an extension that keeps track of the recently used file list and any file on position 4 is closed, (open file path 4, close file path 4, and open the top file path)

Comment: And would those approaches make it lose the ability to ctrl+p to past files easily? I like that ctrl+p has a wide memory beyond 3+ tabs.

Comment: Just tried it. I guess it works, thanks.